# Command to completely uninstall puppet in the master server

Tags: linux, centos7, puppetmaster

I want to remove puppetmaster from master server including certificate. I am using puppet open source.

Comment: what do you mean by "puppetmaster from master server", you want to install/remove complete puppet master?

Comment: @asktyagi, yes including certificate

Comment: share what you have tried till now, are you facing any issue?